# Cancel LAContext Evaluation in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, touch-id

I'm trying to write a code in objective C for iphone and basically I'm trying to use touch id sensor with LAContext class. I send a "authentication with biometrics" request and after a while(for example 200 miliseconds) I want to cancel this request. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to cancel this request in my code, the only way that I found was canceling request from user and that needs user action.
Here is my code:

```
LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
NSError *error = nil;
if (true) {
    [context 
evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
                        localizedReason:@"Place your finger?"
                        reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                        }];
```

I really appreciate it if you guys can help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that since iOS 9. There is an `invalidate` method in `CAContext` class.

In your controller, write the code below just right after `[context evaluatePolicy: localizedReason: reply:]`

```
[self performSelector:@selector(invalidateCA) withObject:self afterDelay:0.2];
```

Then declare your method for canceling TouchID

```
- (void)invalidateCA
{
    // you have to get a reference to it when you create CAContext
    [self.context invalidate];
}
```